# latest code collaborator says java SE6 runtime required for installation

Tags: java, macos, code-collaborator

I downloaded last code colloborator client(Download Mac OS X Installers v8.4.8403) from smartbear website. when i tried to install it on my system(Mac OS X 10.9), it throwed an error stating "To open Collaborator client installer you need a java se 6 runtime. would you like to install?" The site clearly stated "Requires: Oracle Java 1.7"

i have java 7_51 installed on my system.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable?

Comment: i have JAVA_HOME environmental variable pointing to the java folder

Comment: Make sure you are using Oracle JDK and not OpenJDK. Uninstall the app and run the installer again, this time with "-manual" option. This way the installer will ask you to point to your JDK directory manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like this in OS X since Apple stopped the support of Java by themselves. Now you can only download Java 7 or 8 from Oracle's website.

You have two options:

1) Simple click `install` when the program asks for it. The app check for Java 6 install, but it will start with your Java 7 (or what you defined in `JAVA_HOME` env variable).

2) Your second option is to start the app from terminal /.../java7/bin.

Comment: The first option worked.. clicked on install and pop up stated that it's going to install java6, installed it and then code collaborator installation started. But when i checked the java version in terminal, it still is java 7. And i have my code collaborator installed :).